# error LNK1169 on global const char*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am experiencing some strange behavior with Visual Studio 2010 and C++.
I have a header file in which I declare some global constants

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

// Macros...
#define SAFE_RELEASE(ptr) { if (ptr) { ptr->Release(); ptr = NULL } }
#define SAFE_DELETE(ptr) { if (ptr) { delete ptr; ptr = NULL; } }

// Constants...
const char* CLASS_NAME = "WinMain";
const char GAME_TITLE[] = "DirectX Window";

const int GAME_WIDTH = 640;
const int GAME_HEIGHT = 480;

#endif
```

My problem comes in with the following line:

```
const char* CLASS_NAME = "WinMain";
```

When it's like this, and I build my solution I get the following 2 errors:

`error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`, and

`error LNK2005: "char const * const CLASS_NAME" (?CLASS_NAME@@3PBDB) already defined in graphics.obj`

Now is strange since a ran a 'find in files' and I definitely do not declare it somewhere else ie no duplicate declarations.

Should I change it to:

```
const char* const CLASS_NAME = "WinMain";
```

OR

```
const char CLASS_NAME[] = "WinMain";
```

It compiles just fine! But as far as I know `char* x` is equivalent to `char x[]`, and the fact that I'm enforcing 'const-ness' on both the pointer and the pointed-to value should make no difference.... or does it?

I'm a bit new to C++ development on the Windows platform, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The SAFE_RELEASE macro and it's friends are *not safe at all*. Use smart pointers, don't `delete` or `Release()` yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132453/error-lnk1169-one-or-more-multiply-defined-symbols-found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mistake is that you did not declare your constants as *constants*. In C++ syntax (as well as in C) in order to declare a constant pointer you have to do this

```
const char* const CLASS_NAME = "WinMain";
```

Note that your `GAME_TITLE`, `GAME_WIDTH` and `GAME_HEIGHT` are correctly declared as constants, which is why they give you no trouble. Only the `CLASS_NAME` is declared incorrectly, i.e. as non-constant.

Constants in C++ have internal linkage by default, which is why you can define them in header files without violating the One Definition Rule.

Comment: Thanks!! Just had an Eureka-moment! :)

Comment: Wow, I never thought it can be a problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: can someone explain why you need "const" twice though? Like, is this because this is a constant pointer to a constant character array, or something similar?

Comment: @aquirdturtle: You would read that from right to left so it's a 'constant pointer to a constant char'. So neither the pointer nor the value pointed to by that pointer can change.

Answer (score 5):

Don't *define* variables in headers. When you include that header in more than one translation unit, you have multiple copies of the definition.

Only *declare* variables there (using `extern`), and define them in precisely one translation unit.

That said... an exception to this rule can be made for constants of built-in types, since they have internal linkage by default.

That is, the two programs are functionally identical:

```
const int x = 42;
int main() {}
```

```
static const int x = 42;
int main() {}
```

This ensures that one copy is generated for *each* translation unit, avoiding the issue altogether.

I *think* the same is true for arrays. So, sure, `const` it up and knock yourself out.

---

> But as far as I know 'char* x' is equivalent to 'char x[]',

Only in a function parameter list. In a fully-fledged declaration, `x` will take the array type with dimension determined from the initialiser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) Just a question on your comment "When you include that header in more than one translation unit, you have multiple copies of the definition." isn't the #include guards supposed to suppress that kind of behavior?

Comment: And I got this cool article which alleviated some of the misconceptions I had about char pointers: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/ link :)

Comment: @mnemonic: No. Include guards can only function _within_ a translation unit. That is, they prevent problems caused by `#include "hi.h" \n #include "hi.h"` in the same .cpp file, or more complex equivalents reached by headers including other headers... The include guards, like the rest of your C++ code, don't exist any more at the link stage. Consider the collections `{1,2,3,3}` and `{3,4,5,5,6,6}` you can remove duplicates in each collection to get `{1,2,3}` and `{3,4,5,6}`, but when you perform your final step of merging those collections you still have a duplicate: `{1,2,3,3,4,5,6}`.

Comment: Also cf declare/define in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987648/2128797) with structs. Hope it helps.:)

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because if you include the file in multiple compilation units, you are declaring a variable of that name in each unit. Compilation is not a problem, but when the linker tries to link it sees multiple definitions of the same variable. You can get away with this with `const int` variables and `const char GAME_TITLE[]` because they have static linkage, but for string literals (which are essentially `char` arrays) you will get this error. You should be able to fix the problem using `extern`