# fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found in game programming

Tags: c++, oop, allegro5

I've been training to use object orientated programming in c++ but I keep getting this error:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int WIDTH" (?WIDTH@@3HA) already defined in GameObject.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int HEIGHT" (?HEIGHT@@3HA) already defined in GameObject.obj
1>Spaceship.obj : error LNK2005: "int WIDTH" (?WIDTH@@3HA) already defined in GameObject.obj
1>Spaceship.obj : error LNK2005: "int HEIGHT" (?HEIGHT@@3HA) already defined in GameObject.obj
1>C:\Users\ted\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\fullSpace\Debug\fullSpace.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

However to me, it seems that the entire code is written properly and the two ints are only mentioned in the Global header and all objects seem to be inheriting properly. However, like I just said, I'm a beginner in OOP so I really need an opinion : It is also worth mentioning that I am using allegro 5 to create a side shooter.

This is the code :

(main):

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_acodec.h>

#include <list>


#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Spaceship.h"
#include "Globals.h"



//controls

bool keys[] = {false, false, false, false, false};
enum KEYS{UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, SPACE};

//globals
Spaceship *ship;

std::list <GameObject *> objects;
std::list <GameObject *>::iterator iter;
std::list <GameObject *>::iterator iter2;



//prototypes



//main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //shell variables
    bool done = false;
    bool render = false;

    float gameTime = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int gameFPS = 0;

    //project variables

    ship = new Spaceship();


    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *shipImage = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *cometImage= NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *explImage = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bgImage = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *mgImage = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *plImage = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *mgImage2 = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *fgImage = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *titleImage= NULL;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *lostImage = NULL;


    //allegro variables
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *event_queue = NULL;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *font18;



    //initiate variables
    if(!al_init())
        return -1;

    display = al_create_display(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    if(!display)
    return -1;

    //addon installation

    al_install_keyboard();
    al_init_image_addon();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();
    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_install_audio();
    al_init_acodec_addon();

    //project init

    font18 = al_load_font("arial.ttf", 18, 0);
    al_reserve_samples(15);




    bgImage = al_load_bitmap("layer1.png");
    mgImage = al_load_bitmap("layer2.png");
    plImage = al_load_bitmap("starMG.png");
    mgImage2 = al_load_bitmap("layer3.png");
    fgImage = al_load_bitmap("layer4.png");




    shipImage = al_load_bitmap("spaceship.png");
    al_convert_mask_to_alpha(shipImage, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255));



    cometImage = al_load_bitmap("asteroid-1-96.png");
    explImage = al_load_bitmap("explosion_3_40_128.png");

    titleImage = al_load_bitmap("Shooter_Title.png");
    lostImage = al_load_bitmap("Shooter_Lose.png");



    //object init
    ship->init(shipImage);


    //iter list
    objects.push_back(ship);


    srand(time(NULL));

    //timer init and startup

    event_queue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / 60);

    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());

    al_start_timer(timer);
    gameTime = al_current_time();

    while(!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);

        //input
        if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                done = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                keys[LEFT] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                keys[RIGHT] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                keys[UP] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                keys[DOWN] = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                keys[SPACE] = true;
                break;


            }
        } else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            switch(ev.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                done = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                keys[LEFT] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                keys[RIGHT] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
                keys[UP] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
                keys[DOWN] = false;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                keys[SPACE] = false;
                break;
            }
        }



        else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            render = true;

            //fps
            frames++;
            if(al_current_time() - gameTime >= 1)
            {
                gameTime = al_current_time();
                gameFPS = frames;
                frames = 0;
            }

            //shipUpdate

            if(keys[UP])
                ship ->moveUp();
            else if(keys[DOWN])
                ship ->moveDown();
            else
                ship->resetAnim(1);

            if(keys[LEFT])
                ship ->moveLeft();
            else if(keys[RIGHT])
                ship -> moveRight();
            else
                ship ->resetAnim(0);

        }
        //render

            if(render && al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue))
            {
                render = false;

                //begin render
                for(iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter)
                    (*iter)->render();




                //Flip Buffers
                al_flip_display();
                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
            }
        }

                //destroy objects



        //visual objects
    al_destroy_bitmap(cometImage);
    for(iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter)
        (*iter)->destroy(shipImage);
        iter = objects.erase(iter);

    al_destroy_bitmap(explImage);
    al_destroy_bitmap(bgImage);
    al_destroy_bitmap(mgImage);
    al_destroy_bitmap(fgImage);
    al_destroy_bitmap(titleImage);
    al_destroy_bitmap(lostImage);

        //audio objects
    /*
    al_destroy_sample(shot);
    al_destroy_sample(boom);
    al_destroy_sample(song);
    al_destroy_sample_instance(songInstance);
    */


        //shell objects
    al_destroy_font(font18);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_event_queue(event_queue);
    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

(Globals.h):

```
#pragma once

int WIDTH = 1024;
int HEIGHT = 800;

enum ID{PLAYER, ENEMY, BULLET, BORDER, MISC};
enum STATES{TITLE, PLAYING, LOST};
```

(GameObject.h):

```
#pragma once


#include "Globals.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <allegro5/allegro5.h>

#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>



class GameObject
{
private:
    int ID;
    bool alive;
    bool collidable;

protected:
    float x;
    float y;

    float velX;
    float velY;

    int dirX;
    int dirY;

    int boundX;
    int boundY;

    int maxFrame;
    int curFrame;
    int frameCount;
    int frameDelay;
    int frameWidth;
    int frameHeight;
    int animationColumns;
    int animationDirection;

    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image;

public:
    GameObject();
    void virtual destroy(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image);

    void init(float x, float y, float velX, float velY, int dirX, int dirY, int boundX, int boundY);
    void virtual update();
    void virtual render();

    float getX() {return x;}
    float getY() {return y;}

    void setX(float x) {GameObject::x = x;}
    void setY(float y) {GameObject::y = y;}

    int getBoundX() {return boundX;}
    int getBoundY() {return boundY;}

    int getID() {return ID;}
    void setID(int ID) {GameObject::ID = ID;}

    bool getAlive() {return alive;}
    void setAlive(bool alive) {GameObject::alive = alive;}

    bool getCollidable() {return collidable;}
    void setCollidable(bool collidable) {GameObject::collidable = collidable;}

    bool checkCollisions(GameObject *otherObject);
    void virtual collided(int objectID);
    bool collidableCheck();
};
```

(GameObject.cpp):

```
#include "GameObject.h"

GameObject::GameObject()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;

    dirX = 0;
    dirY = 0;

    boundX = 0;
    boundY = 0;

    maxFrame = 0;
    curFrame = 0;
    frameCount = 0;
    frameDelay = 0;
    frameWidth = 0;
    frameHeight = 0;
    animationColumns = 0;
    animationDirection = 0;

    image = NULL;

    alive = true;
    collidable = true;

}

void GameObject::destroy(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image)
{
    if(image != NULL)
        al_destroy_bitmap(image);

}
void GameObject::init(float x, float y, float velX, float velY, int dirX, int dirY, int boundX, int boundY)
{
    GameObject::x = x;
    GameObject::y = y;

    GameObject::velX = velX;
    GameObject::velY = velY;

    GameObject::dirX = dirX;
    GameObject::dirY = dirY;

    GameObject::boundX = boundX;
    GameObject::boundY = boundY;

}

void GameObject::update()
{
    x += velX*dirX;
    y += velY*dirY;
}

void GameObject::render()
{

}

bool GameObject::checkCollisions(GameObject *otherObject)
{
    float oX = otherObject->getX();
    float oY = otherObject->getY();

    int obX = otherObject->getBoundX();
    int obY = otherObject->getBoundY();

    if(x + boundX > oX - obX &&
       x - boundX < oX + obX &&
       y + boundY > oY - obY &&
       y - boundY < oY + obY
       )
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}

void GameObject::collided(int objectID)
{

}
bool GameObject::collidableCheck()
{
    return alive && collidable;
}
```

(SpaceShip.h):

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

class Spaceship : public GameObject
{
private :
    int lives;
    int score;
    int animationRow;

public :
    Spaceship();

    void destroy(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image);

    void init(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image = NULL);

    void update();
    void render();

    void moveUp();
    void moveDown();
    void moveLeft();
    void moveRight();

    void resetAnim(int pos);

    int getLives(){return lives;}

    int getScore() {return score;}

    void looseLife() {lives--;}
    void addPoint() {score++;}

    void collide(int objectID);



};
```

(SpaceShip.cpp):

```
#include "Spaceship.h"

    Spaceship::Spaceship()
    {}

    void Spaceship::destroy(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image)
    {
        GameObject::destroy(image);
    }
    void Spaceship::init(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image)
    {
        GameObject::init(20, 200, 6, 6, 0, 0, 10, 12);

        setID(PLAYER);
        setAlive(true);

        lives = 3;
        score = 0;

        maxFrame = 3;
        curFrame = 0;
        frameWidth = 46;
        frameHeight = 41;
        animationColumns = 3;
        animationDirection = 1;

        animationRow = 1;

        if(image != NULL)
        {
            Spaceship::image = image;
        }
    }

    void Spaceship::update()
    {
        GameObject::update();
        if(x < 0)
            x=0;
        else if ( x > WIDTH)
            x = WIDTH;
        if(y < 0)
            y = 0;
        else if (y > HEIGHT)
            y = HEIGHT;
    }
    void Spaceship::render()
    {
        GameObject::render();

        int fx = (curFrame % animationColumns) *frameWidth;
        int fy = animationRow *frameHeight;

        al_draw_bitmap_region(image, fx, fy, frameWidth, frameHeight,
            x - frameWidth /2, y - frameHeight /2, 0);

    }

    void Spaceship::moveUp()
    {
        animationRow = 0;
        dirY = -1;

    }
    void Spaceship::moveDown()
    {
        animationRow = 2;
        dirY = 1;
    }
    void Spaceship::moveLeft()
    {
        curFrame = 2;
        dirX = -1;
    }
    void Spaceship::moveRight()
    {
        curFrame = 1;
        dirX = 1;
    }

    void Spaceship::resetAnim(int pos)
    {
        if(pos == 1)
        {
            animationRow = 1;
            dirY = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            curFrame = 0;
            dirX = 0;
        }
    }

    void Spaceship::collide(int objectID)
    {
        if(objectID == ENEMY)
            lives--;

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [error LNK1169 on global const char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772206/error-lnk1169-on-global-const-char)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The two `int` variables are *defined* in the header file. This means that every source file which includes the header will contain their definition (header inclusion is purely textual). The of course leads to multiple definition errors.

You have several options to fix this.

1. Make the variables `static` (`static int WIDTH = 1024;`). They will still exist in each source file, but their definitions will not be visible outside of the source file.
2. Turn their definitions into declarations by using `extern` (`extern int WIDTH;`) and put the definition into **one** source file: `int WIDTH = 1024;`.
3. Probably the best option: make the variables `const` (`const int WIDTH = 1024;`). This makes them `static` implicitly, and also allows them to be used as compile-time constants, allowing the compiler to use their value directly instead of issuing code to read it from the variable etc.

Comment: Thank you very much but now I have a new error, I keep getting   'fullSpace.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file     for hundreds of .dlls, can you help again?

Comment: @user2189708 That's a different question. Have a search first.

Comment: @user2189708 That's a very different and unrelated problem. It probably has more to do with your Visual Studio project settings. You're better off asking a new SO question (after you've verified it's not already answered here).

Comment: @Angrew: Why it fails with `const char*`?

Comment: @VikasPatidar You mean why putting `const char *whatever = something;` into a header results in multiple definition? That's because the `const` applies to the `char`, not to the pointer. So it's the same case as the non-static, non-const `int`. So again, you have to provide only a declaration (`extern`) in the header, or make the variable `static` or constant: `const char * const whatever = something;`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't put variable definitions in header files, as these will then be a part of all source file you include the header into.

The `#pragma once` is just to protect against multiple inclusions in the same source file, not against multiple inclusions in multiple source files.

You could *declare* the variables as `extern` in the header file, and then *define* them in a single source file. *Or* you could declare the variables as `const` in the header file and then the compiler and linker will manage it.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19740915/1592639).

In the Project’s Settings, add  `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` to the Linker’s **Command Line** options.

From [MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19740915/1592639): "Use /FORCE:MULTIPLE to create an output file whether or not LINK finds more than one definition for a symbol."

That's what programmers call a "quick and dirty" solution, but sometimes you just want the build to be completed and get to the bottom of the problem later, so that's kind of a ad-hoc solution.
To actually avoid this error, provided that you want

```
int WIDTH = 1024;
int HEIGHT = 800;
```

to be shared among several source files, just declare them only in a single .c / .cpp file, and refer to them in a header file:

```
extern int WIDTH;
extern int HEIGHT;
```

Then include the header in any other source file you wish these global variables to be available.

Comment: Silencing the linker is not a solution. If you want to allow multiple definitions for functions, use the `inline` specifier. That's its primary use case. Starting with C++17 there's also support for inline variables. Another option would be to declare variables in a header that's included into multiple translation units. This is done using the `extern` specifier.

Comment: It was not a solution for me. warning LNK4088: image being generated due to /FORCE option; image may not run...

Answer (score 1):

```
const int WIDTH = 1024;
const int HEIGHT = 800;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, but why?

Comment: try to search 'one definition rule'

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got error message `one or more multiply defined symbols found`, and I find another error message shows `xxx function is already defined in ooo.dll`, but in my project doensn't reference `ooo.dll` at all.

Then I recall I use `vcpkg` to install `ooo.dll` possibly globally before, so use `vcpkg` to remove uninstall `ooo.dll package`, and build again, the error is solved and build success.

Comment: In my case vcpkg was also the cause. When I changed [Use Vcpkg], [Install Vcpkg Dependencies] and [Use AutoLink] from "Yes" to "No" the errors were gone. This can be found under Project properties -> Configuration properties -> vcpkg.

Answer (score 0):

just add /FORCE as linker flag and you're all set.

for instance, if you're working on CMakeLists.txt. Then add following line:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "/FORCE")
```

Comment: This might work, but it's terrible practice. Please, for the love of god and all things holy, **do not do this**. Fix the root issue instead.

Comment: YES! I AGREE, FIX THE ROOT ISSUE.  Rewrite Visual C's compiler to work like Visual C#.  The compiler shouldn't even be capable of including the same file or any of its elements more than once.  Make the compiler automatically link every symbol with no need for extern or header files.