# already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj,

Tags: c++, oop, linker

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517658/fatal-error-lnk1169-one-or-more-multiply-defined-symbols-found-in-game-programm) solution but I am not able to understand it for my case.

My project Structure is

- ConsoleApplication1.cpp (main)
- BST.h
- BST.cpp
- help.cpp

Now my main is

```cpp
#include "BST.h"
#include "help.cpp"

int main()
{
    BST b1;

    b1.insertion(5);
    b1.insertion(3);
    b1.insertion(2);
    b1.insertion(5);

    b1.insertion(7);
    b1.insertion(9);
    cout << predecessor(b1, 9)->data;
```

My BST.h is

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node {
    int data;
    node* leftchild, * rightchild, * parent;
};

class BST {
private:
    node* root;

public:
    BST();
    node* rooter();

    void insertion(int);
    void outleftandright();
    node* search(int x);

};
```

and BST.cpp is

```cpp
#include "BST.h"

node* BST::search(int x)
{
    if (x == root->data)
    {
        return root;
    }
    node* temp = root;
    while (temp)
    {

        if (x < temp->data)
        {
            temp = temp->leftchild;
        }
        else if (x > temp->data)
        {
            temp = temp->rightchild;
        }
        else if (x == temp->data)
        {
            return temp;
        }
    }
}


void BST::outleftandright() {
    node* temp = root;
    cout << "LEFT\n";
    while (temp)
    {
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->leftchild;
    }
    temp = root;
    cout << "Right\n";
    while (temp)
    {
        cout << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->rightchild;
    }

}

BST::BST()
{
    root = nullptr;
}

node* BST::rooter()
{
    return root;
}

void BST::insertion(int data)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = new node;
        root->data = data;
        root->leftchild = nullptr;
        root->rightchild = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        node* temp = root;
        while (true)
        {

            if (data <= temp->data)
            {

                if (temp->leftchild == nullptr)
                {
                    temp->leftchild = new node;
                    temp->leftchild->parent = temp;
                    temp = temp->leftchild;

                    temp->data = data;
                    temp->leftchild = nullptr;
                    temp->rightchild = nullptr;
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->leftchild;
            }
            else if (data > temp->data)
            {
                if (temp->rightchild == nullptr)
                {
                    temp->rightchild = new node;
                    temp->rightchild->parent = temp;
                    temp = temp->rightchild;
                    temp->data = data;
                    temp->leftchild = nullptr;
                    temp->rightchild = nullptr;
                    break;
                }
                temp = temp->rightchild;
            }
        }

        temp->data = data;
        temp->leftchild = nullptr;
        temp->rightchild = nullptr;
    }

}
```

and help.cpp is

```cpp
#include "BST.h"

node* minimum(node* b1)
{
    while (b1->leftchild != nullptr)
    {
        b1 = b1->leftchild;
    }
    return b1;
}

node* maximum(node* temp)
{
    while (temp->rightchild != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->rightchild;
    }
    return temp;
}



node* successor(BST b1, int x)
{
    node* temproot = b1.search(x);
    node* temproot1 = temproot;
    if (temproot->rightchild != nullptr)
    {
        return minimum(temproot->rightchild);
    }
    else
    {
        node* y = temproot->parent;
        while (y != nullptr && temproot == y->rightchild)
        {
            temproot = y;
            y = temproot->parent;
        }
        if (y == nullptr)
        {
            return maximum(temproot1);
        }
        else {
            return y;
        }
    }
}

node* predecessor(BST b1, int x)
{
    node* temproot = b1.search(x);
    node* temproot1 = temproot;
    if (temproot->leftchild != nullptr)
    {
        return maximum(temproot->leftchild);
    }
    else
    {
        node* y = temproot->parent;
        while (y != nullptr && temproot == y->leftchild)
        {
            temproot = y;
            y = temproot->parent;
        }
        if (y == nullptr)
        {
            return minimum(temproot1);
        }
        else {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

Now When I did not had help.cpp and the functions inside help.cpp were in my Consol1Application1.cpp, it was working fine, but now it is giving error

```
1>help.obj : error LNK2005: "struct node * __cdecl maximum(struct node *)" (?maximum@@YAPEAUnode@@PEAU1@@Z) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj
1>help.obj : error LNK2005: "struct node * __cdecl minimum(struct node *)" (?minimum@@YAPEAUnode@@PEAU1@@Z) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj
1>help.obj : error LNK2005: "struct node * __cdecl predecessor(class BST,int)" (?predecessor@@YAPEAUnode@@VBST@@H@Z) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj
1>help.obj : error LNK2005: "struct node * __cdecl successor(class BST,int)" (?successor@@YAPEAUnode@@VBST@@H@Z) already defined in ConsoleApplication1.obj
1>C:\Users\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\source\repos\Week 13 Assign\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

How to deal with it? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't include `.cpp` files, only header files.

Comment: Your bug is here `#include "help.cpp"`

Comment: You need `help.h` that contains just the function declarations without the code, and then use `#include "help.h"`

Comment: @Barmar, add this to an answer and I will tick it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't `#include "help.cpp"`. That creates definitions of the functions in `main.obj`. When you then link that with `help.obj` (as you presumably are), you get duplicate definitions.

Instead, you should create `help.h` that contains just the function declarations from `help.cpp`. Then use

```
#include "help.h"
```

in the other files.

Comment: The example in the question only shows it being included in a single translation unit.  I have to believe that `help.cpp` was *also* being compiled and linked as a translation unit.  This is backed up by the contents of the error messages.

Answer (score -1):

help.cpp wont work
try renaming to help.h
ho